# A simple exercise but I cannot find the mistake the function doesn't work

Tags: javascript

Can't find the problem function doesn't work. I want to to be sure that ps input is a number if not give alert. Without the function it works I suppose I have in the function something missing

Comment: if (input instanceof Number) {} ?

Comment: You'll need to post the code here as text, elaborate on what it's supposed to do, and detail. What debugging you've done.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know.  Was there something we could help you with?

Comment: function myFunction(){
var ps = prompt("Bitte geben sie ihre PS an.", " ");
var age = prompt("Bitte geben sie ihr Alter an", " ");
var austria = + ps + 100 / + age + 50;
var result = alert("Sie zahlen pro Monat:" + (Math.floor(austria)));

if(ps < 100){
alert("Bitte geben sie eine Zahl ein.");
    }
   }

Comment: **In the question**, [edit] it. Give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isNaN()` function to check weather the entered prompt is number or not.

```js
function myFunction()
{
 var ps = prompt("Bitte geben sie ihre PS an.", " ");
 while(isNaN(ps))
 {
 alert('Enter a number')
 ps = prompt("Bitte geben sie ihre PS an.", " ");
 }
 var age = prompt("Bitte geben sie ihr Alter an", " "); 
 while(isNaN(age))
 {
 alert('Enter a number')
 age = prompt("Bitte geben sie ihr Alter an", " ");
 }
var austria = + ps + 100 / + age + 50; 
var result = alert("Sie zahlen pro Monat:" + (Math.floor(austria)));
 if(ps < 100)
{
 alert("Bitte geben sie eine Zahl ein."); 
}
 }
 myFunction();
```